# Basic HTTP Authentication в Flask не работает

Tags: python, http, flask, аутентификация

Я делаю Flask приложение и мне нужна HTTP Basic Authentication, а она у меня не работает

Я делаю это, как в [примере](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VW8qJxy4XcQ)

Как мне исправить данную проблему?

Импортированные библиотеки

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, render_template_string, request
import json
```

Фрагмент кода с авторизацией

```py
@app.route('/user/<string:name>')
def user(name):
    request.authorization.username
    request.authorization.password

    with open('json/users.json', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        x = f.read()
    data = json.loads(x)
    user = data[name]
    return render_template('about_user.html',
        _name=user['name'],
        _age=user['age'],
        _discord=user['discord']
    )
```

Сама ошибка

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужно проверить, если ли `request.authorization` и сделать возвращение `make_response`

Правильный код:

```py
@app.route('/user/<string:name>')
def user(name):
    if request.authorization:
        request.authorization.username
        request.authorization.password

        with open('json/users.json', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        x = f.read()
    data = json.loads(x)
    user = data[name]
    return render_template('about_user.html',
        _name=user['name'],
        _age=user['age'],
        _discord=user['discord']
    )
    else:
       return make_response('Could not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})
```